# JAR file not found during build in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jar

hello i am trying to run java jsp/servlet application using netbeans but i am getting error message it say

> C:\Users\isslam\Desktop\jsp2_allfiles\servlet_jsp\netbeans\book_apps\musicStore\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1009 Warning: Could not find file C:\Users\isslam\Desktop\jsp2_allfiles\Program Files\NetBeans 6.0 M9\enterprise4\modules\ext\standard.jar to copy.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I downloaded the standard.jar but i am not sure if it is the right one and i added it to the Libraries and still giving me the same error. the path he is giving me is not real path i can not find it in fact it is kind of wrong

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is almost a year old, but I had the same problem and fixed it so I thought I'd chime in.

It looks like you're using Murach's Java Servlets and JSP exercise files, which is what I'm using too. Well, those are kind of old and include some old libraries.

To resolve the issue, open your project in Netbeans. Right click on it and select properties. Select libraries. You should see a JSTL library that is outdated. Remove it from the project. Now add the updated JSTL library by clicking Add Library and selecting the new JSTL library.